# Doing loot runs with vehicles in DayZ

Tags: dayz-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When does loot respawn in DayZ?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76541/when-does-loot-respawn-in-dayz)

How do you execute loot runs while traveling in a vehicle? I've noticed that loot, like zombies, doesn't spawn while you're inside of a vehicle. But unlike zombies, loot doesn't seem to spawn when I exit either. Seems the only way I can get loot to spawn is to approach the lootzone/building on foot from a distance.

So, if you want to bring your car with you, and do a loot run through a town, wat do? Do you park in a semi-safe location outside of town, go in on foot, grab loot and then return to the car before moving on to the next town? Do you know of any faster/smarter strategies?

Comment: The 2nd point in SevenSidedDie's answer in [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76541/when-does-loot-respawn-in-dayz) answers this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a general guide on how loot spawns, see [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76541/when-does-loot-respawn-in-dayz). The relevant point is that loot will only spawn when a player is in a donut around the building with an inside radius of 30m and an outside radius of 120m.

You are probably parking your vehicle inside the 30m "hole" where loot spawning doesn't happen. You will have to park >30m away from your target and approach on foot, or drop off a passenger in that >30m zone before driving up to the building.